# The derivative of $(\sin(x) - 1)^{\cos(x) + 1} + (\sin(x) + 1 )^{1 - \cos(x)}$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the derivative of $ f(x) = (\sin(x) - 1)^{\cos(x) + 1} + (\sin(x) + 1 )^{1 - \cos(x)}$

I don't know how to approach this one. I tried to apply the natural logarithm to both functions on the right side, then derive it and I get the same result as Wolfram Alpha but I have several problems with that. First of all when I apply it to $(\sin(x) - 1)^{\cos(x) + 1}$ I get :
$$ (\cos(x) + 1)\cdot\ln(\sin(x) - 1) $$
which does not make any sense since $\sin(x) - 1 \in [-2, 0] $
and the problem with $\sin(x) + 1$ is the number zero since $\sin(x) + 1 \in [0, 2] $ and I can't take the logarithm of non-positive numbers.

The second thing that bothers me is that when I enter the function $g(x) = (\sin(x) - 1)^{\cos(x) + 1}$ into Wolfram Alpha, it tells me that the domain and range of this function are empty sets but isn't for example:
$$ g(\frac{\pi}{2}) = (\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) - 1)^{\cos\frac{\pi}{2} + 1} = (1-1)^{0+1} = 0^1 = 0$$

a valid thing to do in the real numbers?

EDIT:
This is homework for my Mathematical Analysis class (first year of college). We work only with the set of real numbers. We defined the domain of the logarithm function to be:   $\mathscr{D}_{log} = \langle 0 , +\infty \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Well, you actually can, e.g. $\log(-1)=i\pi$. (taking the principal branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of real analysis, the domain of $f$ is the set $\{\pi/2+\pi n: n\in\mathbb Z\}$. The definition of derivative at point $x$ requires $f$ to be defined on some open interval containing $x$. Since $f$ fails this requirement, it fails to have a derivative. Answer: "does not exist" / "not defined",  whichever form you prefer.

Another popular example of this kind is "find the derivative of $\ln \ln \sin x$".

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Alexander's advice was awful.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I also asked my professor and the answer is that there is no answer (in terms of real analysis) and the domain and range are of course not empty sets. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For $(sin(x)-1)^{cos(x)+1}$ we have,

$$(sin(x)-1)^{cos(x)+1}=e^{log((sin(x)-1)^{cos(x)+1})}=e^{(cos(x)+1)log(sin(x)-1)}=e^{cos(x)log(sin(x)-1)}(sin(x)-1)=(e^{log(sin(x)-1)})^{cos(x)}(sin(x)-1)...$$

Comment: $e^{(ab)} = \left(e^{a}\right)^b$, not $e^{a}e^b$.

Comment: just use a substitution for $(cos(x)+1)log(sin(x)-1)$ instead

Comment: Sorry that was stupid from my side!

Comment: @Thorben We've all done that before.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Can you show that

$$
i=\frac{\ln(-1)}{\pi}
$$

the proof (consider the famous Euler equation....) might help explain what happens when you take $\ln\left(\sin x-1\right)$ for certain $x$.

Comment: and ln(0) is minus infinity, it isn't undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try

$$(sin(x)-1)^{cos(x)+1}=e^{log((sin(x)-1)^{cos(x)+1})}=e^{(cos(x)+1)log(sin(x)-1)}=e^{t}$$

where $t=(cos(x)+1)log(sin(x)-1)$

and the you can use the normal chain rule and product rule. This should also work for the other part ($sin(x)+1$ etc)

Comment: This approach and my approach give me the same result and I get the correct answer according to Wolfram Alpha but the problem is that we only work with real numbers, we "don't know" what the imaginary unit is. My domain and range is "limited" to $\langle -\infty , +\infty \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: then "don't know" that taking the log of a negative number is a problem

Comment: this method is perfectly valid and would be accepted in any exam

Comment: I don't know what to say to that. This is homework for my Mathematical Analysis class (first year of college) and we work only with the set of real numbers. We defined the domain of the logarithm function to be: $D_f = \langle 0, +\infty \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

Comment: that domain is wrong. just use the proof and don't worry about the problems you've raised. They don't matter at your level: when they do matter (and they won't) you'll know what a complex number is. They're perfectly natural elements of maths. You wont ever be able to use a proof with logs in it without introducing the problems you've raised. The problem has probably already come up over and over again without you noticing.

Comment: How exactly is that domain wrong? If you define the exponential function over the reals, you get a function which "throws" $\mathbb{R}$ into the interval $\langle 0, +\infty \rangle$, i.e. $\exp \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \langle 0, +\infty \rangle$ and the inverse function would then be $\ln \colon \langle 0, +\infty \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we were actually shown numerous examples where the solution was: there is no solution (because we work with reals).

Comment: And that's where the second part of my question comes in. If I don't have a domain/range (over the reals) (as Wolfram Alpha claims), then there is nothing to differentiate but if WA is making a mistake (which I don't know and that's why I am asking about the validity of my $g(\frac{\pi}{2})$ example), then there are maybe some points which I can derive but then again I need a formula to calculate the derivative and that's the first part of my question (is there a way to get the derivative of $f(x)$ without the use of the natural logarithm or not).

Comment: the domain is wrong beacuse ln(-1) is not undefined. you're getting tied up in a problem which doesn't exist, then trying to invent a problem. If you want an answer that doesn't involve logarithms then say - your thought process is excellent btw. Use this example to learn about complex numbers, not as a method to extend your differentiation techniques "in ignorance". Does your professor perhaps ask for a technique without logs? Or specifically without complex numbers? Perhaps try using the substitution cos(x) + 1  = t and changing sin(x) into cos(x) via an argument shift.